# R, compute index based on co-occurrence matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix of species occurring in sites and I want to compute the following formula for each pair `ab` of species:
[image]

where `Ra` and `Rb` are the occurrences of species `a` and `b` respectively and `S` the number of sites where `a` and `b` co-occur.

So far, I have this solution which is very slow (actually way too slow for my matrix):

```
set.seed(1)
# Example of binary matrix with sites in rows and species in columns
mat <- matrix(runif(200), ncol = 20)
mat_bin <- mat
mat_bin[mat_bin > 0.5] <- 1
mat_bin[mat_bin <= 0.5] <- 0
rownames(mat_bin) <- paste0("site_", seq(1:nrow(mat_bin)))
colnames(mat_bin) <- paste0("sp_", seq(1:ncol(mat_bin)))

# Number of occurrences for every species
nbocc <- colSums(mat_bin)

# Number of cooccurrences between species
S <- crossprod(mat_bin)
diag(S) <- 0 

# Data frame with all the pair combinations
comb <- data.frame(t(combn(colnames(mat_bin), 2)))
colnames(comb) <- c("sp1", "sp2")
comb$Cscore <- 0

# Slow for_loop to compute the Cscore of each pair
for(i in 1:nrow(comb)){
  num <- (nbocc[[comb[i, "sp1"]]] - S[comb[i, "sp1"], comb[i, "sp2"]]) *
    (nbocc[[comb[i, "sp2"]]] - S[comb[i, "sp1"], comb[i, "sp2"]])

  denom <- nbocc[[comb[i, "sp1"]]] * nbocc[[comb[i, "sp2"]]]

  comb[i, "Cscore"] <- num/denom
}
```

A first solution could be to parallelize the `for-loop`, but maybe a more optimized solution exist.

Answer (score 1):

Like you have started with `S`, you could do the full calculation in a vectorized manner based on matrices.

This would look as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
# Example of binary matrix with sites in rows and species in columns
mat <- matrix(runif(200), ncol = 20)
mat_bin <- mat
mat_bin[mat_bin > 0.5] <- 1
mat_bin[mat_bin <= 0.5] <- 0
rownames(mat_bin) <- paste0("site_", seq(1:nrow(mat_bin)))
colnames(mat_bin) <- paste0("sp_", seq(1:ncol(mat_bin)))

# Number of occurrences for every species
nbocc <- colSums(mat_bin)

# Number of cooccurrences between species
S <- crossprod(mat_bin)

resMat <- (nbocc - S) * t(nbocc - S) / 
  outer(nbocc, nbocc, `*`)

# in the end you would need just the triangle
resMat[lower.tri(resMat)]
```

Comment: I was looking for a matrix-based answer, thank you. However, both results do not match perfectly. Could you detail the logic of your answer?

Comment: I have now checked `identical(comb$Cscore, resMat[lower.tri(resMat)])` and it gives `TRUE` for me. Could it be that you have not used the same seeding for the two cases?

Comment: It does not seem to come from the seeding. I just tried with this matrix: `mat_bin <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
                  ncol = 4)` and the `identical(comb$Cscore, resMat[lower.tri(resMat)])` gives `FALSE`.

Comment: Not sure, maybe if you can show the resulting numbers from the two variants with this small matrix we can spot something?

Comment: Thank you for your time. With `comb$Cscore` I obtain `c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)`. With `resMat[lower.tri(resMat)])`: `c(0, 1, 0.25, 1, 0.33, 0)`